# PostAsync never returns when client application is hosted on virtualized server

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-web-api, c#-5.0

My console application contains an asynchronous function in order to invoke a remote method on my server:

```
public async Task<Int32> ApiCall(String Uri, Object Item)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
    HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<Object>(Item, jsonFormatter);

    response = await Client.PostAsync(Uri,content).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Int32>();
    }
    else if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    {
        throw new MyException();
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This method is invoked periodically (and synchronously) in this way:

```
public int ApiCallSync(MyObject Item)
{
    try
    {
        int result = ApiCall("<MethodName>", Item).Result;
        return result;
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly on different environments (Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 on VirtualBox, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7) with the exception of a system consisting of virtualized Windows Server 2012 Datacenter (VMWare). In this system, after a random period of time, PostAsync stops working and never returns to the client. 
I've seen different examples that advise to use asynchronous methods to prevent deadlocks, but in my case I need to call remote methods synchronously to maintain the chronological order of the events and I do not know if this is the cause of my problem.

Comment: `I need to call remote methods synchronously to maintain the chronological order of the events` - not at all. Asynchronous code can be just as *serial* as synchronous code; that's one of the main benefits of `async`/`await`.

Comment: As you have not logged your exception, how do you know that PostAsync didn't throw any exception?

Answer (score 2):

That behavior can be caused by deadlock on context synchronization. To prevent that try add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to all async calls in your `ApiCall`.

In your case you should add that method in this line:

```
return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Int32>();
```

so you should change that to:

```
return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Int32>().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The whole description of that problem you can read for example on that blog post: http://blog.ciber.no/2014/05/19/using-task-configureawaitfalse-to-prevent-deadlocks-in-async-code/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is not the async method, but related to the way you try to transform an async call to a sync one.

On this complex subject, their is some nice threads on Stackoverflow.

So if you really can't make ApiCall an async method, you can try the following:

When i need to call async methods synchronously, a secure and easy way to do this is like Microsoft does it in AspNet.Identity.

Below the implementation of their helper, which you can find on the assembly Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core in version 2.0.0.0:

```
internal static class AsyncHelper
    {
        private static readonly TaskFactory _TaskFactory = new TaskFactory();

        public static void RunSync(Func<Task> func)
        {
            _TaskFactory.StartNew<Task>(func).Unwrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func)
        {
            return _TaskFactory.StartNew<Task<TResult>>(func).Unwrap<TResult>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
```

Use it like that:

```
var result = AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => ApiCall("<MethodName>", Item));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ApiCallSync to

```
public Task<int> ApiCallSync(MyObject Item)
{
    try
    {
        int result = await ApiCall("<MethodName>", Item);
        return result;
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
var result = await ApiCallSync(..)
```